# Merge two sorted linked list using a single function

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Having trouble while achieving two different linked list but using only one function. Code below:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define node struct Node

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} *first = NULL, *second = NULL;
```

This function is used to create the linked list

```
void create(int A[], int n, node *ptr)
{
    struct Node *temp, *last;
    ptr = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    ptr->data = A[0];
    ptr->next = NULL;
    last = ptr;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        temp->data = A[i];
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}

void display(node *ptr)
{
    cout << "Your linked list: ";
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout << ptr->data << " ";
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I'm using array for taking elements function namely "userInput", where array size and pointer will be taken as arguments

```
// taking elements for the linked list
void userInput(int size, node *ptr)
{
    int arr[size];
    cout << "Input linked list element values: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    //! Create the linked list
    create(arr, size, ptr);
    //* Display the linked list
    display(ptr);
}
```

```
int main()
{
    cout << "\t\t-----------------------\n";
    cout << "\t\tCreating the first LL\n";
    cout << "\t\t-----------------------\n\n";
    int s;
    cout << "Enter size: ";
    cin >> s;
    userInput(s, first);

    cout << "\n\n\t\t-----------------------\n";
    cout << "\t\tCreating the second LL\n";
    cout << "\t\t-----------------------\n\n";
    cout << "Enter size: ";
    cin >> s;
    userInput(s, second);

    return 0;
}
```

**After running the code program is unable to display the linked list. How can I achieve two linked lists by only this codebase?**

Comment: Just try `void create(int A[], int n, node &*ptr)`

Comment: please tag the language you are using. The code is C++, so the C tag is offtopic

Comment: `void create(int A[], int n, node *ptr)` only uses `A` for reading, and `n` and `ptr` are passed by value. The function could modify what `ptr` points to but it throws away its value already in the second line. Only that is sufficient to know that this function cannot "create" a list

Comment: Offtopic: `for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)` in C and C++ index starts from `0`.

Comment: `#define node struct Node` Doesn't make much sense in C++. In C, I'd use a `typedef`. `int arr[size];` declares a Variable Length Array which is not part of C++, but it's optional in C. What language are you supposed to use?

Comment: "using a single function": I can't think of a way to do that with more than one function !

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the list pointer to the `create` function as a value, which is a null pointer. The function does not update the global variable.  You should change the `create` function to return the list pointer:

```
struct Node *create(int A[], int n) {
    struct Node *ptr = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
    ptr->data = A[0];
    ptr->next = NULL;
    struct Node *last = ptr;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        struct Node *temp = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(*temp));
        temp->data = A[i];
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
    return ptr;
}

// taking elements for the linked list
struct Node *userInput(int size) {
    int arr[size];
    cout << "Input linked list element values: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    //! Create the linked list
    struct Node *ptr = create(arr, size);
    //* Display the linked list
    display(ptr);
    return ptr;
}

int main() {
    cout << "\t\t-----------------------\n";
    cout << "\t\tCreating the first LL\n";
    cout << "\t\t-----------------------\n\n";
    int s;
    cout << "Enter size: ";
    cin >> s;
    first = userInput(s);

    cout << "\n\n\t\t-----------------------\n";
    cout << "\t\tCreating the second LL\n";
    cout << "\t\t-----------------------\n\n";
    cout << "Enter size: ";
    cin >> s;
    second = userInput(s);

    return 0;
}
```